# C++ fuzz test with libfuzzer.a

Tags: c++, fuzzing, scoverage, libfuzzer

i use libfuzzer.a to code my first fuzz test,
here is my code

```
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *Data, size_t Size) {

int size = Size;
printf("size=%d",Size);
return 0;  // Non-zero return values are reserved for future use.
}
```

but when i run this code ,i got this problem,how case this?

```
WARNING: Failed to find function "__sanitizer_acquire_crash_state".
WARNING: Failed to find function "__sanitizer_print_stack_trace".
WARNING: Failed to find function "__sanitizer_set_death_callback".
INFO: Seed: 3186764919
INFO: -max_len is not provided; libFuzzer will not generate inputs larger than 4096 bytes
INFO: A corpus is not provided, starting from an empty corpus
#2      INITED exec/s: 0 rss: 26Mb
ERROR: no interesting inputs were found. Is the code instrumented for coverage? Exiting.
```

can you help me? thank you

Comment: Could you post your makefile as well? And which sanitizer do you use?

Comment: @KimKuling hello,i don't use any sanitizer in my makefile ,i build it in android aosp ,i use Android.bp to build a cc_binary

Comment: @KimKulling hi ,i also want to know that how to get the rate of test progress when i start my fuzz test,and how long does the test will run?